# Distuingish iOS devices in ASP.NET

Tags: ios, asp.net

Enterprise iOS applications can be distributed outside of Apple Store. I would like to distribute different versions of my enterprise iOS application based on the device model. (eg.: iPhone7,1 device model is equal to iPhone6+)

Is it possible to request "iPhone7,1" kind of device model identifier somehow from ASP.net?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try seeing if the user agent will suffice.

```
string strUserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString().ToLower();
if (strUserAgent != null)
{
    if (Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice == true || strUserAgent.Contains("iphone") || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("blackberry") || strUserAgent.Contains("mobile") || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("windows ce") || strUserAgent.Contains("opera mini") || 
        strUserAgent.Contains("palm"))
  {
        Response.Redirect("DefaultMobile.aspx");
  }
}
```

Otherwise try using the Use 51Degrees.mobi .NET Mobile API To Detect The User-Agent. It can be found at: http://www.51degrees.mobi/Products/NETMobileAPI

Hope this helps ;)